# nodejs teradata returns "nodeJava_java_math_BigDecimal{}" instead of decimal value in the resultset?

Tags: node.js, teradata, bigdecimal

i am running a simple select query. the code runs fine and its returning the resultset as well showing all the column values which are in character format but showing "nodeJava_java_math_BigDecimal{}" insted of decimal format columns ?

```
var Teradata = require('node-teradata');  


var config = { 
url: 'jdbc:teradata://abc.com/database=abab', 
 username: '****',   
  password: '****',  
  driver: './jars/',  
  minPoolSize: 1,
    maxPoolSize: 100,   
    keepalive: {   
      interval: 60000,   
      query: 'SELECT 1',   
      enabled: true   
    }     
};   

var teradata = new Teradata(config);

var sql = "select name,QTY from products where id='700018'";

return teradata.read(sql)
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

the result its printing on console is:

```
[{name:'Apple Juice',QTY:nodeJava_java_math_BigDecimal{}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retype the properties of the returned object with the JavaScript types you know you'll be working with, using methods like `Number([...])` or `.toString()`

```
return teradata.read(sql)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.map(respObj => objExtractor(respObj));
});

function objExtractor(teradataObj) {
    return {
        name: teradataObj.name.toString(),
        QTY: Number(teradataObj.QTY).toFixed(0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that I'm assuming your teradata query `read()` returns an array, which a `Select ... where` generally does.

Comment: Good non-callback style, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Quoting CraZySacX from [here](https://github.com/CraZySacX/node-jdbc/issues/100):

> When you get back a node-java wrapped object
>   (nodeJava_java_math_BigDecimal), you have access to all of the
>   functions exposed by the Java API in both a sync and async form.
>
> For example, the Java 7 BigDecimal API has a function called intValue

Which in your case would be:

```
return teradata.read(sql)
  .then(function(response) {

       response[0].QTY.intValue(function(err, intVal){
           var newQTY = intVal;
           console.log(newQTY);
        }

  });
```